# How to click on an image and execute a function with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

I am currently developing a website and i need to apply a certain functionality. I have an image and I need it to behave like a button. When the user clicks the image i need some Javascript to be executed but i dont seem to get it right for a reason! Here is my code:

```js
   onload = function(){
    var yoda = document.getElementById("masteryoda");
    console.log(yoda);

    yoda.onclick() = function () {
    yoda.style.opacity="0.5";
    }​
    }
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/A_sunflower.jpg/260px-A_sunflower.jpg"
alt="Mountain View" id="masteryoda" style="width:304px;height:228px;"></div>
```

Comment: Does your code find something for yoda ? I mean is there an image with id yoda ?

Comment: yes there is! Thats why i have console.log(yoda); in order to make sure the image is picked! and yes it does pick it up i can see it in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="image" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Alternatively, add an event listener on the image.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: add a listener for click event. It will be easy to debug.

```
 onload = function(){
  var yoda = document.getElementById("masteryoda");
  console.log(yoda);

  yoda.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.opacity = '0.5';
  })
}
```

Also, there is error in your code: you trying to run function `onclick()` and set value of another function to it. Change `onclick()` to `onclick`:

```
onload = function(){
  var yoda = document.getElementById("masteryoda");
  console.log(yoda);

  yoda.onclick = function() {
    yoda.style.opacity = '0.5';
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change `yoda.onclick()` to `yoda.onclick`.

`yoda.onclick = function () {`

`yoda.style.opacity="0.5";`

`}`​

Answer (score 0):

Try THis

```js
function changeOpacity() {
 var yoda = document.getElementById("masteryoda");
    yoda.style.opacity="0.5";
    }
```

```html
<div onclick='changeOpacity()'>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/A_sunflower.jpg/260px-A_sunflower.jpg"
alt="Mountain View" id="masteryoda" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</div>
```